# A flower blossom: bending petals gradually towards the ground

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm struggling to figure out a way to bend realized instances downwards gradually, the lower they are positioned on the point geometry.

I'm modelling a dandelion flower. I'm attaching the project file here for reference. The goal is that the petals on the top will be shorter and rather straight, while the older and lower growing ones will bend backwards. I checked all the other related posts here and at BlenderArtists, to no avail so far.

[Project file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zrzzxjxrd13ab6g/AABRvSv-oHlPstlgw_WzHHkqa?dl=0)

Ref img:
[image]

Figuring out, how to regulate the amount by which they also stretch as they bend, would be great, but for that I can imagine a workaround and it's not necessarily a problem in this case.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, but if you use the node `Vector Rotate` you have to switch the type to *Axis Angle*.
Only then you can influence the necessary direction of the rotation.

[image]

You get the rotation axis if you calculate the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of your position and the up-vector.

Additionally, I added a little bit to the structure here, and instead of instantiating the petals directly at the existing points, I added a distribution of points on the surface of the object using `Distribute Points on Faces`.

To make the petals a little smaller towards the top, they are also scaled. In this example I use the *Z* position and the node `Map Range`.

[image]

Comment: OMG yes! Thank you! It's amazing to find the last bit missing in the puzzle. Your help is very appreciated!